# Return SQL Row Position but sort it before

Tags: sql, sqlite, lua

Ok guys so I'm basically ordering the SQL Table like this:

`"SELECT * FROM tablelevel ORDER BY prestige DESC, level DESC;"`

And I Print the Table in a Scoreboard and it's all fine.

The problem is, now I wanted to get a position from a "playerID". Something like (What i'm about to write is just an example and doesn't work):

`1st -> ("SELECT * FROM tablelevel ORDER BY prestige DESC, level DESC;") // Sort it`

`2nd -> ("SELECT * FROM "1st" WHERE playerID = 'x' ") // Get Pos`

Is it possible to get the position of a row without adding a column with the position?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: SQL server, SQLite, MySQL...?

Comment: SQLite, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the position is to create a temporary table, and use that table's [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE scoreboard AS
SELECT * FROM tablelevel ODER BY prestige DESC, level DESC;

SELECT * FROM scoreboard WHERE rowid = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks, That's Perfect

Comment: Just one more question, should I remove the temporary Table after?

Comment: Also if I "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE scoreboard" again, will it overwrite the previous one?

Comment: Yes. No. (See [TEMP Databases](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temp_databases).)